# react-admin Selectinput with default value

Tags: react-native, react-admin

Is it possible to render SelectInput with default value selected? I need to load the page with a default language selected. thanks.

My code:

```
export const CT_SELECT_I18N = [
    {id: 'en', text: 'English'},
    {id: 'pt', text: 'Português'},
    {id: 'es', text: 'Español'},
];

const renderSelect = ({
                          meta: {touched, error} = {},
                          input: {...inputProps},
                          ...props
                      }) => (
    <SelectInput
        error={!!(touched && error)}
        helperText={touched && error}
        {...inputProps}
        {...props}
        fullWidth
        source="idioma"
        choices={Constants.CT_SELECT_I18N}
        translateChoice={false}
        optionValue="id"
        optionText="text"
    />
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the prop `initialValue` for this.

Your selectinput would look like

```
     <SelectInput
        error={!!(touched && error)}
        helperText={touched && error}
        {...inputProps}
        {...props}
        fullWidth
        source="idioma"
        choices={Constants.CT_SELECT_I18N}
        translateChoice={false}
        optionValue="id"
        optionText="text"
        initialValue={"en"}
    />
```

More here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#common-input-props

Answer (score 0):

Since React Admin version 3.3.0 you can use the `defaultValue` prop.

```
<SelectInput
    error={!!(touched && error)}
    helperText={touched && error}
    {...inputProps}
    {...props}
    fullWidth
    source="idioma"
    choices={Constants.CT_SELECT_I18N}
    translateChoice={false}
    optionValue="id"
    optionText="text"
    defaultValue="en"
/>
```

In the React Admin documentation, the defaultValue prop is documented as a valid option for form inputs, and it's described as a prop that can be used to set the default value of a form field.
See: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#defaultvalue